# EF DataContext: Code is being executed so long

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have the following property in dataContext:

```
    public DbSet<CollectionSite> CollectionSites { get; set; }
```

where `CollectionSite` has approx 30-40 properties.

I try the following code:

```
        var query = _context.CollectionSites
            .Where(cs =>
            cs.IsActive &&
            cs.OpenToPublic &&
            (NIDACollections == null || cs.NIDACollections == NIDACollections.Value) &&
            (SAPCollections == null || cs.SAPCollections == SAPCollections.Value) &&
            (observedRequested == null || cs.ObservedCollection == observedRequested.Value) &&
            (electronicCC == null || cs.RegulatedElectronicCCF == electronicCC.Value) &&
            (alcoholTestType == null || cs.BreathAlcohol == alcoholTestType.Value))
            ;
```

where all these variables like `NIDACollections` etc are `bool?`.
This code just created `IQueryable<CollectionSite>` object and don't execute a request to source, but this code is being executed 4-5 seconds (i7, 16Gb of RAM). Why so long? What is wrong in my code?

Comment: How many rows are in the table? Do you have an index on any of those columns? Pick the most selective one, and place a non-clustered index on it

Comment: but what matter how many rows in the table, if I just combine query?

Comment: To me it looks two things might be wrong. Either as @Milney said you have a lot of rows to process or you use Lazy Loading with `NIDACollections`, `SAPCollections`etc. Try and use Eager Loading.

Comment: The query isn't executed until you iterate over it, by adding a `.ToList()` or using it in  a `foreach`

Comment: Decompose query creation into multiple calls to `Where()`. That way you will find which rows execute slow. Probably there are properties in objects in conditions with complex getters. Another option is to use Visual Studio Profiler if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Run a SqlProfiler, If you are using sql server management studio with Sql server it's built in under tools, If you are using other database try to log generated queries from EF context.

Get the query generated from you Linq statement and run it on the database directly and analyze the Query plan. See what is causing this query to slow down. My guess would be (table scan due to missing indexes).

Comment: SqlProfiler does not show anything and it would be surprised if it shows anything because I don't call to DB, just combine a request!

Comment: @OlegSh you are using a DbSet, which suggests that you are trying to access data in a database. When you iterate over the query(-results) then a database call will happen.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, but I don't call ToList() or something else